# How to adjust the `absolute text-height` including the header/footer/footnote (if any)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry, height

I would like to have a document of a given absolute text-height (say 20cm) (from the header to last line, including footer/footnote, if any). Currently the settings are as in the following document. But only the text-height is 20cm and the header are not included in this 20cm.

Of course I can decrease about 1cm from textheight in order that the absolute text-size to be about 20cm, but I prefer an exact solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[textwidth=12cm,
textheight=20cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\chapter{blablabla}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\ \ Title}
\fancyhead[OR]{\leftmark\ \thepage}

jhjhjh
\blindtext[10]
jhjhhj\footnote{\blindtext[1] }
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

**Edit**:
Let me mention that I have measured the text-height of the current solution provided below (by egreg) by the measurement tool of Acrobat reader. It seems that the text-height including the header is greater that 20cm, see the image below.

[image]

Comment: try `\usepackage[total={12cm,20cm}]{geometry}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to the options for `geometry` also `includehead` and `includefoot`; I recommend also adding `heightrounded`, which will change the text height as little as possible to ensure an integer number of lines fit.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[
  textwidth=12cm,
  textheight=20cm,
  includehead,includefoot,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{blablabla}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\ \ Title}
\fancyhead[OR]{\leftmark\ \thepage}

jhjhjh
\blindtext[10]
jhjhhj\footnote{\blindtext[1] }
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

It's better to set the page style in the preamble, if possible.

Comment: I realized that if one uses `height=20cm` instead of  `textheight=20cm`, the issue is solved.