# How to have the same top/bottom margins (from the footer/header, if any) and the same left/right margins in the book class

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry, height

I have the following document. Thanks to the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272591/ the absolute text-height is 20 cm (text-height+footer+header=20cm).

I would that the left and the right margins to be exactly of the same size,  the same for top and the bottom margin.

Added: bottom and top should be the same, including the header and footers.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[textwidth=12cm,textheight=20cm,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 

\fancyhead[EL]{\thepage\ \ Title}
\fancyhead[OR]{text\ \ \thepage}


\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `oneside` option to the `book` class should provide the same spacings for the left and right margin

Comment: bottom and top should be the same, including the `header` and `footers`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I apologize for the inconvenience, but your solution to use the option `oneside` has some conflicts with my header settings, see the complied document, after adding `oneside` the headers of the pages change. Hence I think adding `oneside` option is not the solution for this document.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes I edited the question.

Comment: Simply use the option to geometry: `centering` or `marginratio=1:1`.

Comment: @Bernard Ok thanks, for the left and the right margin, this answer the question. Do the bottom and the top margin with this option include header/footer?

Comment: I guess not, since you included them in the main body. You can check it adding the option `showframe` to geometry. If you're under Windows and use SumatraPDF, it has a tool for measurement (with the `M` key).

Comment: Geometry treats everything except the text area as a "margin".  However, the footers and headers are both specified by their baselines so balancing them depends on the font size used.